# Эскиз видео

Tags: android, java

Как можно отобразить эскиз видео в android?

Comment: учитесь гуглить    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android+video+thumbnail

Comment: @metalurgus гуглил, но не смог найти информацию, как это делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неужели мне все за вас нужно делать? Пятая ссылка по запросу, что я дал.

```
Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path_to_file, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

Comment: @metalurgus спасибо, но я имел ввиду что я до того как задать вопрос я искал в гугле и не смог найти информацию как это делать наверное потому что не знал как об этом спросить. 
большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: @eldqs, поэтому я и написал, чтобы вы учились искать. Ибо не умеете.

Comment: @metalurgus спасибо, буду знать

Comment: @metalurgus библиотека, которую я использую, не принимает Bitmap, а только id ресурса, можно ли как-то во время работы программы перевести bitmap, который был создан в resource?

Comment: @eldqs, нет. И что же это за абсолютно бесполезная библиотека, которая не принимает битмапы?

Comment: @metalurgus caldroid https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid, очень жаль, что нельзя как-то это обойти.